# RubberDucky Detector

Tags: c++, windows, qt

RubberDucky which will look like a regular usb drive but it will act like a keystorke device.

This C++ program will help you to find whether the connected device is actually a USB device is actually an USB device or a key stroke injector(Rubber Ducky)

**What this program does:** When the program is started it is measure the count of the USB devices and it will measure the count of the input devices.
When USB drive is inserted the count of USB drive will increase so it will inform the user that the connected device is an USB device. If rubber ducky is inserted(though it looks like USB it a Key stroking device) input devices count will increase so it will inform the user that the connected device is a Ruber Ducky.

Here is the .hpp file

```
// SWAMI KARUPPASWAMI THUNNAI
#ifndef RUBBERDUCKYDETECTOR_HPP
#define RUBBERDUCKYDETECTOR_HPP

#include <QDialog>
#include <QtConcurrent>

namespace Ui {
class RubberDuckyDetector;
}

class RubberDuckyDetector : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit RubberDuckyDetector(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~RubberDuckyDetector();
public slots:
    /**
     * @brief checkPresenceOfKeyStrokeInjector This method is actually used to detect the presence
     * of malicious devices like rubber ducky. [RUN THIS SLOT AS A SEPERATE THREAD]
     */
    void checkPresenceOfKeyStrokeInjector();
    /**
     * @brief informKeystrokeInjector This slot will inform the user that the keystroke injector has
     * been inserted.
     */
    void informKeystrokeInjector();
    /**
     * @brief informUSBDrive This method is used to inform the presence of USB device
     */
    void informUSBDrive();
signals:
    /**
     * @brief driveIsKeyStrokeInjector This signal will be emitted if the connected
     * input drive is actually a KeyStroke injector
     */
    void driveIsKeyStrokeInjector();
    /**
     * @brief driveIsUSB This method will check if the drive is a USB device or not.
     */
    void driveIsUSB();

private:
    Ui::RubberDuckyDetector *ui;

    // Initial no of USB drives present in the computer
    volatile int initial_usbDrivesCount = 0;
    // Initial no of Input devices present in the computer
    volatile int initial_inputDevicesCount = 0;
    // A thread to check for the keystroke injector
    QFuture<void> checkForKeyStrokeInjectoThread;
    // The state of the thread [RUNNING/TERMINATED]
    volatile bool running = true;
    // Private method declarations

    /**
     * @brief getCountOfUSBDevices This method will get the total no of usb drives present in the system
     * @returns the total no of usb drives
     */
    int getCountOfUSBDevices();
    /**
     * @brief getCountOfInputDevices This method will be useful to get the count of input devices
     * @return count of input devices
     */
    int getCountOfInputDevices();

};

#endif // RUBBERDUCKYDETECTOR_HPP
```

And the .cpp file

```
// SWAMI KARUPPASWAMI THUNNAI
#include "rubberduckydetector.hpp"
#include "ui_rubberduckydetector.h"
#include <QFileInfo>
#include <QDir>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinUser.h>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QException>

RubberDuckyDetector::RubberDuckyDetector(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::RubberDuckyDetector)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    // Initialize the count of usb drives
    initial_usbDrivesCount = getCountOfUSBDevices();
    initial_inputDevicesCount = getCountOfInputDevices();
    checkForKeyStrokeInjectoThread = QtConcurrent::run(this, &RubberDuckyDetector::checkPresenceOfKeyStrokeInjector);
    connect(this, SIGNAL(driveIsKeyStrokeInjector()), this, SLOT(informKeystrokeInjector()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(driveIsUSB()), this, SLOT(informUSBDrive()));
 }

RubberDuckyDetector::~RubberDuckyDetector()
{
    running = false;
    checkForKeyStrokeInjectoThread.cancel();
    checkForKeyStrokeInjectoThread.waitForFinished();
    delete ui;
}
//=========================================================
//          PRIVATE METHOD DEFINITIONS
//=========================================================
int RubberDuckyDetector::getCountOfUSBDevices()
{
    int totalRemovableDrives = 0;
    QDir driveList;
    for(QFileInfo drive : driveList.drives())
    {
        QString driveLetter = drive.absoluteFilePath();
        LPCWSTR driveType = (const wchar_t*) driveLetter.utf16();
        if(GetDriveType(driveType) == 2)
        {
            totalRemovableDrives++;
        }
    }
    return totalRemovableDrives;
}

int RubberDuckyDetector::getCountOfInputDevices()
{
    try{
    UINT totalDevices;
    GetRawInputDeviceList(NULL, &totalDevices, sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICELIST));
    return totalDevices;
    }
    catch(...){return 0;}
}

//=========================================================
//        PUBLIC SLOT DEFINITIONS
//=========================================================

void RubberDuckyDetector::checkPresenceOfKeyStrokeInjector()
{
    while(running)
    {
        try{
            // Once a new device is inserted
            int keystrokeDeviceCount = getCountOfInputDevices();
            // If the input devices count increses then it is a keystroking device
            if(keystrokeDeviceCount>initial_inputDevicesCount)
            {
                emit driveIsKeyStrokeInjector();
                initial_inputDevicesCount = keystrokeDeviceCount;
            }
            // If decreases user has unplugged an input device
            if(keystrokeDeviceCount<initial_inputDevicesCount)
            {
                initial_inputDevicesCount = keystrokeDeviceCount;
            }
            int usbDeviceCount = getCountOfUSBDevices();
            // If the usb devices count increases then it is a USB device
            if(usbDeviceCount>initial_usbDrivesCount)
            {
                emit driveIsUSB();
                initial_usbDrivesCount = usbDeviceCount;
            }
            // If decreases user has unplugged an USB device
            if(usbDeviceCount<initial_usbDrivesCount)
            {
                initial_usbDrivesCount = usbDeviceCount;
            }
        } catch(...){}
    }
}

void RubberDuckyDetector::informKeystrokeInjector()
{
    QMessageBox::critical(this, "CRITICAL", "You have inserted a keystroke injector");
}

void RubberDuckyDetector::informUSBDrive()
{
    QMessageBox::information(this, "INFORMATION", "You have inserted a USB device");
}
```

See entire project: [https://github.com/VISWESWARAN1998/CyberGod-KSGMPRH](https://github.com/VISWESWARAN1998/CyberGod-KSGMPRH/tree/4cc469943c3de2c65182997b13a3e64960f184d2)

The program will look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a data race in your code. You access `running` reading and writing. `volatile` ***does not mean threadsafe***. Therefore, your code exhibits undefined behaviour.

---

Neither `getCountOfUSBDevices` nor `getCountOfInputDevices` need to be associated with `RubberDuckyDetector`. They can be `static` or—even better—free standing functions.

---

If possible, use C++11 features for `connect` instead of `SLOT` and `SIGNAL`:

```
connect(this, &RubberDuckyDetector::driveIsKeyStrokeInjector, 
        this, &RubberDuckyDetector::informKeystrokeInjector);
connect(this, &RubberDuckyDetector::driveIsUSB, 
        this, &RubberDuckyDetector::informUSBDrive);
```

This will enable the compiler to check whether the signal and slot a) exist and b) are compatible.

---

To remove possible data races in `checkForKeyStrokeInjectoThread` have `checkPresenceOfKeyStrokeInjector` take two arguments. Then you don't have to store the `initial_usbDrivesCount` in your class at all.

---

You switch naming conventions. `initial_usbDrivesCount` is both `camelCase` and `python_case`.

---

This is personal preference, but if you put the doxygen comments into the implementation, your header gets a lot smaller and easier to read through, e.g.

```
namespace Ui {
class RubberDuckyDetector;
}

int getCountOfUSBDevices();
int getCountOfInputDevices();

class RubberDuckyDetector : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit RubberDuckyDetector(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~RubberDuckyDetector();
public slots:
    void checkPresenceOfKeyStrokeInjector(int initial_usb, int initial_input);
    void informKeystrokeInjector();
    void informUSBDrive();
signals:
    void driveIsKeyStrokeInjector();
    void driveIsUSB();

private:
    Ui::RubberDuckyDetector *ui;          //!< User interface handle.

    QFuture<void> checkForKeyStrokeInjectoThread; //!< concurrent keystroke thread
    QAtomicInt running = 1;               //!< the state of the thread [RUNNING/TERMINATED]
};
```

That way you're also more likely to expand the documentation in your implementation file, not only a brief comment:

```
/**
 * @brief Perpetually checks changes in the count of USB devices.
 * @param initial_usb must be the count of initial usb devices
 * @param initial_input must be the count of initial input devices
 *
 * This method should get run in a separate thread, as it will not exit
 * as long as `running.load()` does not return `0`. Use an `std::thread`,
 * `QConcurrent::run` or `QThread`, for example:
 *
 * @code
 * QConcurrent::run(this, &RubberDuckyDetector::checkPresenceOfKeyStrokeInjector,
 *                  getCountOfUSBDevices(), getCountOfInputDevices());
 * @endcode
 *
 * RubberDuckyDetector's destructor will set `running` to `0`, so destroy
 * the RubberDuckyDetector instance if you do not want to continue.
 *
 * @sa RubberDuckyDetector::~RubberDuckyDetector()
 * @sa getCountOfUSBDevices()
 * @sa getCountOfInputDevices()
 */

void RubberDuckyDetector::checkPresenceOfKeyStrokeInjector(int initial_usb, int initial_input)
{
    while(running.load())
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Also, you won't have to recompile all depending files in order to improve the documentation.